# Learning PHP and having do/while issue

Tags: php

I am currently trying to learn PHP and am stuck on a do/while with else/if loop and am totally baffled. Would appreciate if anybody could let me know where i am going wrong with this.

```
<?php
    $rollCount = 0;
    $sixCount = false;
    do {
        echo "<p>So you want to roll a 6 ? </p>";
    } while($sixCount == false);
        $roll = rand(1,6);
        $rollCount ++;
        if($roll != 6) {
            $sixCount = false;
            echo "<p>You just rolled a " .$roll. " .</p>";
        }
        else {
            $sixCount = true;
            echo "<p>Nice, you just rolled a 6</p>";
        }


    echo "<p>It took {$rollCount} rolls to land 6... What are the odds!</p>";
    ?>
```

I think i may have written an infinite loop, as the preview screen i am working on just shows loading animation.

My little mind tries to look at it like this.

While $sixCount is equal to false, $roll a random number between 1 and 6 and add a +1 to roll count.

IF the $roll does not = to 6, than the $sixCount is false and print "you just rolled a $roll" or else $sixCount is true and you just rolled a 6.

I try to simplify it in my mind by putting into a sentence and transferring it into PHP. Is this the wrong way to look at PHP ?

Appreciate all help on this. Thanks!!

Comment: You don't change `$sixCount` in the body of the loop. So the `$sixCount == false` condition is always true.

Comment: "While $sixCount is equal to false, $roll a random number between 1 and 6 and add a +1 to roll count." --- how do you think php knows what part of your code to loop over?

Comment: You _do_ know the body of the loop is from `do` to the `while`, and **not** the code that comes after your `while` statement there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of the do...while loop. You need to put all your conditions and output into the `do` part, and the `while` part simply defines the condition that should allow the `do` set to keep looping.

Try shifting your code under the `while` line into the `do` statement:

```
$rollCount = 0;
$sixCount = false;

echo "<p>So you want to roll a 6 ? </p>";

do {
    $roll = rand(1,6);
    $rollCount++;
    if($roll != 6) {
        $sixCount = false; // this line is unnecessary 
        echo "<p>You just rolled a {$roll}.</p>";
    }
    else {
        $sixCount = true;
        echo "<p>Nice, you just rolled a 6</p>";
    }
} while($sixCount == false);

echo "<p>It took {$rollCount} rolls to land 6... What are the odds!</p>";
```

An alternative, using the `while` construct without `do` would possibly be more applicable to the way you've laid out your code:

```
$rollCount = 0;
$sixCount = false;

echo "<p>So you want to roll a 6 ? </p>";

while ($sixCount == false) {
    $roll = rand(1,6);
    $rollCount++;
    if($roll != 6) {
        $sixCount = false; // this line is unnecessary
        echo "<p>You just rolled a {$roll}.</p>";
    }
    else {
        $sixCount = true;
        echo "<p>Nice, you just rolled a 6</p>";
    }
}

echo "<p>It took {$rollCount} rolls to land 6... What are the odds!</p>";
```

Comment: Hi Scrowler, thanks for the answer, I altered my code above so that the while condition instead of ($sixCount == false) I just changed to($sixCount)and I deleted the whole $sixCount = false line in the IF statement and it worked. HOWEVER, after looking at your have, it is written in a way that makes more sense. As you said "You need to put all your conditions and output into the do part, and the while part simply defines the condition that should allow the do set to keep looping". This is made a lot more apparent in your code whereas my one was confusing me. Appreciate the help and Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are writing the code you want to continuously execute until it rolls a 6 is outside of the while loop, this is what the code should look like.

```
<?php
$rollCount = 0;
$sixCount = false;
echo "<p>So you want to roll a 6 ? </p>";
do{
    $roll = rand(1,6);
    $rollCount ++;
    if($roll != 6) {
        $sixCount = false;
        echo "<p>You just rolled a " .$roll. " .</p>";
    }
    else {
        $sixCount = true;
    }
}while($sixCount == false);

echo "<p>Nice, you just rolled a 6</p>";
echo "<p>It took {$rollCount} rolls to land 6... What are the odds!</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Harrison, that code makes a lot more sense to me. I feel like such a newbie the way i wrote it above. Wish i could vote you up but i need 15 rep first and also i've already given the correct answer to scrowler. But i appreciate your help, big thanks ! :)

Comment: Thanks Dan! Always happy to be of help. :)